# replacing null value

Tags: sql, presto

If i am using

```
select coalesce(firstname, surname, petname) as column_name


select isnull(firstname, surname) as column_name
```

Where all return the first non-null column, if all the columns are null, how can I assign what to replace the null value in output with?

Typically as below for just checking for one column, I know I can insert value if null as below

```
 select coalesce(column_name, "value if null") as column_name
```

Also, can COALESCE and ISNULL be used interchangeably?

Thanks!

Comment: You have answered your own question.  If you want to guarantee that some non `NULL` value would always be generated by the call to `COALESCE`, then the _last_ value should be some literal/constant.

Comment: By constant do you mean add "value if null" to the end of select coalesce(firstname, surname, petname) as column_name ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: Thank you!, also from my use I feel this way but want to confirm, is coalesce and isnull mostly same thing?

Comment: That I don't know off the top of my head.  Just check Presto's documentation to be certain.  Or, you could just test both functions.  If the both support more than 2 parameters, then likely they are just synonyms of each others.

Answer (score 1):

Presto does not have `isnull` function.

Presto does have [`coalesce`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#coalesce) syntax which takes arbitrary number of arguments; it's not a function, because it guarantees arguments are lazy-evaluated

Comment: How is `nullif` equivalent to `coalesce`? Coalesce returns the first non-null value in a list, while nullif returns null if the two arguments are equal.

Comment: Right, fixed, thanks @Stevoisiak